# Android Studio installed Android API 26 and 27 SDKs -- why are they not in build-tools folder?

Tags: cordova, android-studio

I checked my /android/sdk/build-tools folder on the way to checking why my cordova CLI was not working and found a few SDKs installed up to 25.0.0. I opened Android Studio to check the SDKs downloaded and the list included APIs 26 and 27 checked as "Installed."

If they are installed, why don't I see them listed in /build-tools?

This is important because my AndroidManifest.xml specifies android:targetSdkVersion="27" I assume that means I need SDK 27 installed on my Mac to generate the release apk of the cordova file.

Environment:
iMac, High Sierra v10.13.3
Android Studio 3.0.1
cordova 8.0.0

Comment: Could I improve the question and commentary to prevent any more downvotes?

Answer (score 0):

In Android Studio, in the SDK Manager, under the SDK Tools tab, there is listed "Android SDK Build-Tools 28-rc-1." When you select the checkbox for "Show Package Details" below right and click on the arrow next to the package name, then a long list of SDK Build-Tools appears.

I was able to select the missing 26 and 27 successfully and download them. Their folders now show up among the others in the sdk/build-tools folder.